# Instantiate ConnectionConfiguration in Smack 4.1

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am implementing a chat feature in my android app. So I have installed an open fire server and Smack Client library and now I have written a code to connect with the server but I am getting an error which states that ConnectionConfiguration is an abstract class.So i cant instaniate. Could you give me some idea about the instantiation of ConnectionConfiguration in SMACK 4.1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use the example below:

```
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setUsernameAndPassword(USER_ID+ "@" + DOMAIN, key);
    config.setServiceName(DOMAIN);
    config.setHost(DOMAIN);
    config.setPort(PORT);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

    mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    try {
        mConnection.connect();
    } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Excluding: config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());