# asmack/Smack 4.1 on android setting up

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have been looking for how to add smack to Android Studio even though i have read for 2 weeks many posts but they don't say how to implement this libraries and I am a beginner on android application, people using smack for android says to download this https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack, but there are many libraries and after adding all the libraries as libraries it says that `org.jivesoftware.smack` is not found, I have been looking for an answer but there is nothing in the forums about this.

My question is not how to use but how to set it up on android studio. need help :/

Answer (score 1):

**List of libs that I used:**

- smack-core-4.2.0-alpha1-SNAPSHOT
- smack-im-4.2.0-alpha1-SNAPSHOT
- smack-java7-4.2.0-alpha1-SNAPSHOT
- smack-sasl-provided-4.2.0-alpha1-SNAPSHOT
- smack-tcp-4.2.0-alpha1-SNAPSHOT jxmpp-core-0.4.1
- jxmpp-core-0.4.1
- jxmpp-util-cache-0.4.1

And here you can find useful code example:

[Instantiate ConnectionConfiguration in Smack 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954035/instantiate-connectionconfiguration-in-smack-4-1/28960393#28960393)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy I appreciate your help. The reason I couldn't use it is because I just needed to add it only on the gradle file and not to add the jar files to my project. I have a doubt, after doing a messaging app how can I implement the VoIP feature to it? Using the same xmpp server (open fire)